# How to use Sequitur G2P as python module?

Tags: python

I'm using sequitur g2p to convert text into ipa. That works fine with the cli tool.
I need it as a module to get the translate results directly. That should work as described here: https://github.com/sequitur-g2p/sequitur-g2p/issues/37

But I'm getting the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ sequitur _'

I tried make build / install but they also fail and didn't fix the issue.
I copied the sequitur g2p code into the directory where my python code is. Is this the right approach? I'm new to python.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.
The trick was not to use the Makefile.

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

and it worked.